# ASP.net on Button_click even...textbox value is wrong

Tags: asp.net

I have a form with a textbox1.text="Original Text" and a button.
I run the page and manually change the value in the textbox so that textbox1.text="Changed text".
But when I click the button to save the value to the database, the value the server sees is textbox1.text="Original Text"

What is going on ?

Comment: You need to show us the code, so we can help.

Comment: Wrap your initial "*Textbox1.text*" inside !IsPostBAck as said by @leni.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't post any code but probably what's happenning is that you assign "Original Text" on Page_Load, and you have another button, besides the one that changes to "anither text ", to save to DB, so when this event is trigger the Page_Load changes the text back to the original text.

You should check on the Page_Load event with a !IsPostBack, so when you save to DB wont go again thru the original text.

If (!IsPostBack)
   Textbox1.text = "original text";

Comment: How do I Thank fellow users on here for taking the trouble to answer ?